# How can I calculate the first and second derivatives for a simple moving average in pinescript 5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, derivative

The question was previously answered at this page, but the answer is in version 4.
[Compute slope/derivative values of zigzag line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69972553/compute-slope-derivative-values-of-zigzag-line)
but it was written for version 4.

I would appreciate any help in getting the code in version 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this code in your pinescript panel, then go to the up rigth of this panel and choose 'convert to V5':

[image]

Here is the result :

```
//@version=5
indicator('ZigZagSlope', overlay=true, max_bars_back=500, max_lines_count=300)
prd = input.int(defval=3, title='ZigZag Period', minval=2, maxval=50)
showzigzag = input(defval=true, title='Show Zig Zag')
upcol = input(defval=color.black, title='Zigzag Up Color')
dncol = input(defval=color.black, title='Zigzag Down Color')

float ph = ta.highestbars(high, prd) == 0 ? high : na
float pl = ta.lowestbars(low, prd) == 0 ? low : na
var dir = 0
iff_1 = pl and na(ph) ? -1 : dir
dir := ph and na(pl) ? 1 : iff_1
var max_array_size = 10
var zigzag = array.new_float(0)

add_to_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    array.unshift(zigzag, bindex)
    array.unshift(zigzag, value)
    if array.size(zigzag) > max_array_size
        array.pop(zigzag)
        array.pop(zigzag)

update_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    if array.size(zigzag) == 0
        add_to_zigzag(value, bindex)
    else
        if dir == 1 and value > array.get(zigzag, 0) or dir == -1 and value < array.get(zigzag, 0)
            array.set(zigzag, 0, value)
            array.set(zigzag, 1, bindex)
        0.
Round_it(value) =>
    math.round(value / syminfo.mintick) * syminfo.mintick

dirchanged = ta.change(dir)
if ph or pl
    if dirchanged
        add_to_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)
    else
        update_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)

if showzigzag and array.size(zigzag) >= 4
    var line zzline = na
    float val = array.get(zigzag, 0)
    int point = math.round(array.get(zigzag, 1))
    if ta.change(val) or ta.change(point)
        float val1 = array.get(zigzag, 2)
        int point1 = math.round(array.get(zigzag, 3))
        if ta.change(val1) == 0 and ta.change(point1) == 0
            line.delete(zzline)
        zzline := line.new(x1=point, y1=val, x2=point1, y2=val1, color=dir == 1 ? upcol : dncol, width=2)
        zzline
```